# Missing Ipython Cell Magics

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

In an ipython notebook when I run %lsmagic I get:

```
Available cell magics:
%%!  %%bash  %%capture  %%file  %%perl  %%prun  %%python3  %%ruby  %%script  %%sh  %%sx   %%system  %%timeit
```

I'm expecting to see:

Available cell magics:
%%!  %%HTML  %%SVG  %%bash  %%capture  %%debug  %%file  %%html  %%javascript  %%latex  %%perl  %%prun  %%pypy  %%python  %%python3  %%ruby  %%script  %%sh  %%svg  %%sx  %%system  %%time  %%timeit  %%writefile

(From http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb)

My python version is 2.7.4 and my Ipython version is 0.13.2. Also I'm doing this on Ubuntu. How do I update my ipython magics?

Answer (score 1):

Meta-question: What is the proper etiquette for answering your own questions? Especially if the answer turns out to be rather simple.

The solution to this problem was rather easy. My ipython version was out of date; apt-get had an outdated version of ipython. To remedy this I used pip (which I just learned is the canonical way to update and install python packages) to upgrade ipython to the current stable release.

Comment: On ubuntu you can also use Julian Taylor PPA (Google is your friend) that have more recent version of IPython, use custom Debian patches for system consistency and play nicely with apt. Pip (especially with sudo) can leave Linux systems on weird states.